# Selenium IDE get stuck on clickAndWait command in popup window

Tags: html, browser, selenium, firefox-addon, browser-automation

Every time there is a popup, selenium IDE will get stuck (note the entire page still gets loaded in the background but it get stuck)

Here is where it gets stuck!

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Home</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

You have to select the close option on the popup to close it! hmm

How would you fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just record action of closing this pop-up?

If you can record clicking on this pop-up (e.g.: click | css=img.popup-img) and the problem is that you can't predict if pop-up would appear you can use something like that:

```
clickAndWait | link=Home
gotoIf | javascript{selenium.isElementPresent('css=img.popup-img')} | closePOPUP
goto | continue
label | closePOPUP
click | css=img.popup-img
label | continue
open | http://www.yahoo.com/
```